# SCP issue || Permisson Denied

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, scp

I have two different machines and I tried to copy a file via SCP. I executed below command:

```
scp trial.txt root@10.181.101.21:/unixStudy/trial.txt
```

and then I got "Permission denied" error even though I typed correct password for user root.

I searched a little bit and I gave permission for the scp file to be executable by other users on target machine, but it still didn't work.

Comment: What was the exact error message you received? Don't paraphrase it.

Comment: Is root allowed to use ssh or scp  on remote host?

Comment: Are you allowed to read `trial.txt` locally?

Comment: Try running the scp command again, in verbose mode. The extra information may help you troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I've realized that I should have mentioned ssh. I can ssh to other machine as root or any other user.

Comment: I'm allowed to read trial.txt locally. Exact error message: "permission denied, please try again"

Answer (score 1):

SSH (secure shell) is the fundamental protocol in play.  SCP (secure copy) does the copy process once the SSH connection has been established.  As such, the SSH server on the system being connected to with the `scp` command has to be properly configured for starters.

Very common for `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to contain `PermitRootLogin = no`.
Because you said *tried to scp and typed root password* if you are doing an scp trying to connect to whatever computer as root, you would be denied.

solutions:

- do a simple `ssh` connection first instead of using `scp` and make sure that works for the given usernames.  If it does not, then `scp` under those same parameters will not work.  Syntax is `ssh username@systemname`   If successful with `ssh username@systemname` then doing a corresonding `scp username@system://path_to_file/filename /location_on_current_system` should work
- possibly modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change `PermitRootLogin yes` then restart the sshd daemon/service.  Typically permitrootlogin=no for security reasons but depending on your environment may be irrelevant.  Your call.  If you must connect to the computer acting as the ssh server as root, then you need to change this in sshd_config.

also realize if you're logged in as username `abc123` then doing

```
scp            othersystem:/path_to_file/filename      .
```

is effectively the same as

```
scp     abc123@othersystem:/path_to_file/filename     .
```

make sure you are connecting using the correct passwords with a valid username.

Also, in case you thing typing the *root* password trumps the existing password it does not; you have to type the correct password for the given account name being used.

Comment: Hi, thanks for detailed answer. I can ssh to target machine which is in same network. Then I tried the steps you mentioned and still get the same error. I'm sure that I'm using correct username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove `trial.txt` after `/unixStudy/`.

And, make sure you have correct permission to write in to the `/unixStudy` directory on remote server.

```
scp trial.txt root@10.181.101.21:/unixStudy/trial.txt
```